# useState and if statement causing Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, react-hooks, use-state

What I'm attempting to create is a React component which conditionally renders when the value of the prop boxToggle is true, and also returns null when the user clicks the exit button. What I done to implement this, was to create a local useState called displayUI and assigned the displayUI to true or false using a if statement (this may be the problem, but I cant pinpoint why) depending on the boxToggle prop and inside the onClick of the exit button.

But I receive this error inside the  component:

> Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of
> renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Here is the parent component (im using react-three-fiber)

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

//Packages
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { Canvas, useFrame } from 'react-three-fiber'



import {Box, OrbitControls} from 'drei';


//Components
import Header from './components/Header';
import Homepage from './components/Homepage';
import { Light } from 'three';

//Functions

  //Main App Function
function App() {
  

  const [boxToggle, setboxToggle] = useState(false);  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <Homepage boxToggle={boxToggle}/>
      <Canvas
        colorManagement 
        camera={{position: [0, 5, 10], fov: 60}}
        shadowMap
      >
        <Lights/>
        <RotatingBox
          onClick={()=> setboxToggle(true)}
        />
        <Floor/>
        {/* <OrbitControls/> OrbitControls causes problems with the Raycasting (onClick)*/}
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}

  //Scene Lights
const Lights = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <directionalLight
        intensity={1.5}
        position={[0, 10, 5]}
        castShadow
        shadow-mapSize-width={1024}
        shadow-mapSize-height={1024}
        shadow-camera-far={50}
        shadow-camera-left={-10}
        shadow-camera-right={10}
        shadow-camera-top={10}
        shadow-camera-bottom={-10}
      />
      <ambientLight
        intensity={0.3}
      />
    </>
  )
}

  //Meshes
const RotatingBox = ({onClick})=> {

  const box = useRef();

  const [boxSize, setBoxSize] = useState(false);  

  useFrame(()=>(
    box.current.rotation.y = box.current.rotation.x += 0.01,
    console.log(boxSize)
    )
  )

  return (
      <>
        <Box
          args={ boxSize ? [1, 1, 1]: [2, 2, 2]}
          ref={box}
          castShadow
          onClick={onClick}//cant get onClick Working at all, drei or R3F
          onPointerOver={onClick= ()=> setBoxSize(true)}
        >
          <meshStandardMaterial 
            
            cast
            attach="material" 
            color='yellow'
          />
        </Box>
      </>
  )
}

const Floor = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <mesh
        onClick={()=> console.log("click")} 
        receiveShadow 
        rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} 
        position={[0, -3, 0]}
      >
        <planeBufferGeometry attach='geometry' args={[100, 100]}/>
        <meshStandardMaterial opacity={1} attach='material'/>
      </mesh>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

and the child Homepage component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styles from './Homepage.module.css'

const Homepage = ({boxToggle}) => {

    const [displayUI, setDisplayUI] = useState(false);

    if (boxToggle) { 
        setDisplayUI(true);
    }


    if (displayUI === true) {
        return (
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <button onClick={() => setDisplayUI(false)} className="exit">X</button>
                <div className={styles.title}>
                    <h1>Homepage</h1>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.menu}>
                    <h3>Option 1</h3>
                    <h3>Option 2</h3>
                    <h3>Option 3</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    } else return null
}

export default Homepage
```

Ive tried other stackoverflow answers, but i cant apply them to mine. Most of them are to do with useEffect, or theyre missing a arrow function. This ones got me puzzled i dont even know where to start because im not familiar with Hooks. Thanks

Comment: Whats this `useState` in `Homepage` doing?  Get rid of it and check `boxToggle` directly.

Comment: that's what i originally did, but I also want the Homepage to close with the exit button. Do you have any solutions? thanks for answering.

Comment: can you setup a codepen for the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is cause by your Homepage component.

```
const Homepage = ({boxToggle}) => {

    const [displayUI, setDisplayUI] = useState(false);

    //this generate error because it update the state directly when render
    /*if (boxToggle) {   
        setDisplayUI(true);
    }*/

    //we can fix it by wrap it with a useEffect hook so this effect only trigger when the boxToggle value change
    
    React.useEffect(()=>{
       if (boxToggle) {  
        setDisplayUI(true);
       }
   
    }, [boxToggle])  // <--- dependency that trigger the function call


    if (displayUI === true) {
        return (
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <button onClick={() => setDisplayUI(false)} className="exit">X</button>
                <div className={styles.title}>
                    <h1>Homepage</h1>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.menu}>
                    <h3>Option 1</h3>
                    <h3>Option 2</h3>
                    <h3>Option 3</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    } else return null
}
```

Comment: Wow! thats it! Thank you very much that was fast and informative. I need more understanding of the react lifecycle with useEffect thank you very much

Comment: Sorry. One more thing...its only works once (as in when I exit the Homepage, and then try it again nothing happens), do you have any idea why?

Comment: If the Homepage component is still loaded, that effect will only trigger if the dependency value (boxToggle) change. Based on your logic, it will trigger if boxToggle change from true to false and hit your condition block to do nothing. You can remove dependency array tho (second param) to make it fire every time. Not recommend tho.

Comment: And your  <RotatingBox
          onClick={()=> setboxToggle(true)}
        /> never set the boxToggle back to false. Try to do setboxToggle(!boxToggle) so it will “toggle” the value and trigger the effect

Comment: I believe I got what you trying to achieve. I think you should set the boxToggle state value start with 0, then everytime you hit the rotationbox increment the boxToggle value by one. This way it wont display the homepage ui when init but will set display to true whenever you hit the rotationbox.

Comment: ahh okay, im going to try that solution thank you. btw you are a lot of help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223495/discussion-between-spikethea-and-wei-j-zheng).